# Remove duplicates in Column A when Column B = "Value" in power BI or DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, conditional-formatting

I am having difficulties with PowerBI in removing duplicates from one column based on a condition on another column. My data is something like this
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSN4E.png)
As you can see in the sample data, there are duplicates in ID column that I want to remove when Status = 'False'
The Desired output to be like below
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reHMg.png)

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem here. You want to drop duplicates from ID column when Status = 'False'. However, when there is only one record, and its Status = 'False' you want to keep it, don't you? The output must be a brand-new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In PQ (Transform)

  - Group by ID
  - For each subtable, if there is more than one row, select only the rows where Status=true

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("dZC7DoAgDEX/hdmAt1KE0UEnJx+T8f9/Q5Iq1ESnkpyT21uOw8TOs2nMtuxjHuTgHVF+AZbN2RRhGub13wg1Ag64Bba4BYYIEpAKjw8n3YFIhGSD5rXCh9DrgCDY1/z4PqEVQRVMr09g4X25MLQqoHN4eF5wXg==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Status = _t, Date = _t, Value = _t]),
    #"Correct Error in Source" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{"Status", each if Text.StartsWith(_,"T") then true else false }),

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Correct Error in Source",{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Status", type logical}, {"Date", type date}, {"Value", type number}}),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"deDupFalse", (t)=> if Table.RowCount(t) > 1 then Table.SelectRows(t, each [Status]=true) else t,
            type table[Status=logical, Date=date, Value=number]}        
        }),

    #"Expanded deDupFalse" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "deDupFalse",{"Status","Date","Value"})
in
    #"Expanded deDupFalse"
```

***Data***
[image]

***Filtered***
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron, your response is very helpful